# Need to reload the page 2 times to get userid and info

Tags: facebook, page-refresh

I am trying to integrate facebook connect on my site. Once i login into facebook and then subscribe, the event will fire and its response.status returns 'connected'.  Then i reload the page, but i did not get any userdata. If i manually refresh the page, then only do i get login in the user info

My code is:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        //print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true));
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
        $user = null;
    }
}
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <?php if ($user) { ?>
      Your user profile is
      <pre>
        <?php print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)) ?>
      </pre>
    <?php } //else { ?>
      <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php  //} ?>
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        alert("status " + response.status);
        alert('reload');
        window.location.reload();
    }
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
```

Please help me in solving this

Answer (score 2):

Probably you refreshing the page too fast (so cookies not yet set by the Facebook JS-SDK).

To ensure cookie is set correctly you can use something like this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  if (response.status == 'connected'){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(){
      window.location.reload();
    });
  }
})
```